# TextView below ImageView

Tags: android

I can't place the label where i want. I will show a picture.

[image]

I have the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNombreVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:lines="2"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewNombreVideo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The picture fit the heigh of the imageview, that's ok, and i want to place the textview with the same left of the picture.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNombreVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:lines="2"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewNombreVideo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

below UI design fron this code. as per your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the Gravity option to your TextView:

> android:gravity ="center"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

No need to Take a `RelativeLayout` to adjust, you can simply achieve that with `TextView` bye simply setting `android:drawableTop` attribue of the `TextView`

**Example:** `android:drawableTop="@drawble/yourimage"`

```
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawble/yourimage"
        android:text="Hello"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

use Button instead of ImageView and TextView as..

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Text"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/youriconname"

        />
```

try this may help you..